# Pico W Grounding Problem

Tags: led, pi-pico, breadboard

So im pretty new to hardware stuff and bought a Pico W.
I followed [this](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-pico/6) tutorial and it kind of worked.

The blue cable goes from Pin 2 to the LED, the led to the resistor and the resistor over the purple cable to grounding.

However in the tutorial, the direction of the cable was exactly the other way around, but this did not work for me in any way.

Configuration i listed above and without header Pins -> the LED shines

With Header Pins on only one side to connect the Pico with the Breadboard
-> the LED also shines, as you can see in the picture
[image]

As soon as the second Headerpin-row is added -> LED is not shining anymore
[image]

I also tried other starting Pins(of course activated) and Grounding pins but this doesnt seem to be the issue.

Is there anything different with the Breadboard and grounding ?
Or is there anything im doing fundamentally wrong ?

Comment: "Or is there anything im doing fundamentally wrong" you haven't soldered the header pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you haven't soldered the header pins - which results in unreliable connections you have a PicoW but appear to have followed a tutorial for a Pico.

You haven't explained what code you are running but there are a number of differences between the two.

Comment: I have now soldered the pins and it works fine.